# Failed to create Azure table using Python

Tags: python, azure

I'm trying to create a **table** using  **Azure storage account**, but I got following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./table.py", line 10, in <module>
    table_service.create_table('tasktable')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/storage/table/tableservice.py", line 525, in create_table
    _dont_fail_on_exist(ex)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/storage/_error.py", line 81, in _dont_fail_on_exist
    raise error
azure.common.AzureHttpError: Not Implemented
{"odata.error":{"code":"NotImplemented","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The requested operation is not implemented on the specified resource.\nRequestId:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\nTime:2017-02-06T09:23:30.6719100Z"}}}
```

My code is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from azure.storage.table import TableService, TablePermissions #Entity
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

table_service = TableService(account_name='myAccount', account_key='myKey')

table_service.create_table('tasktable')

task = Entity()
task.PartitionKey = 'tasksSeattle'
task.RowKey = '2'
task.description = 'Wash the car'
task.priority = 100

table_service.insert_entity('tasktable', task)
```

Someone help me.

Comment: Please check the "Kind" of storage account in which you're trying to create this table. More than likely you're trying to create this table in a storage account which doesn't support tables (ZRS, Premium LRS or Blob Storage).

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri I'm trying to crate table in a Blob Storage account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Blob Storage` accounts only support blobs. They don't support tables, queues & files. Because of this, when you try to create a table you're getting this error.

What you need to do is create a `Standard` storage account and use that in your code. Please note that you should not choose `ZRS` or `Premium LRS` redundancy level there as these also don't support tables. `LRS`, `GRS` and `RAGRS` redundancy should work just fine.